# How do I mix non-optional cli arguments with optional ones?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

Using tools.cli, how can I can I create a non-optional argument with optional ones?

I have a function

```
(defn parse-opts
  [args]
  (cli args
  ["-f" "--ifn" "input file"]
 (optional ["-o" "--outp" ".csv pipe delimited output file" 
      :default "assess_pro_out.csv"] identity)
 (optional ["-d" "--debug" "Debug flag for logging." :default 0 
      :parse-fn #(Integer. %)])))
```

that compiles but produces

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ArityException: 
Wrong number of args (2) passed to: PersistentVector
```

when I run my main program without arguments.

If this option is made like the rest

```
(optional ["-f" "--ifn" "input file"] identity)
```

everything works fine.

I just want one parameter to be non-optional.  What am I doing wrong?

I do have a workaround for this, but I'd still like to know if it is okay to mix optional and non-optional arguments to cli.

```
(defn -main 
[& args]
(let [opts (parse-opts args)
      start-time (str (Date.))
      parsed-csv-data (if-not (:ifn opts)
                       (do
                       (println "Usage: assess-chk [-f -ifn] input-file-name")
                       (System/exit -2))
                       (utl/fetch-csv-data (:ifn opts)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: tools.cli's options are always optional. Where did you get your `optional` function from?

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat I've been searching for where I got that code, and I am at a loss to find it. That would answer a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my comment  mail-archive.com/clojure@googlegroups.com/msg49343.html and realize, I need to change all new code to use the new vector options way of doing things. Why don't you answer this question with that information? It's a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old version of tools.cli (probably v0.1.0). For *that* version it appears that you should use `(required ...)` for required options. See the docs at https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli/tree/a741b23f230123179fc518af772f1c057058f7d2

In the current version of tools.cli, options are always optional and the optional and required functions are removed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Going forward with my two current applications, I'll fix this.